# Checking if a vm status is running using virsh and grep - not working when vm name has a space

Tags: awk, grep, virsh

Hi I am using this script to check if a vm is running or not before doing an action

```
#!/bin/bash
vm="PopOS VNC"
vmstate=$(virsh list --all | grep " $vm " | awk '{ print $3}')

if [ "$vmstate" == "x" ] || [ "$vmstate" != "running" ]
then
    echo "VM is shut down" 
else
    echo "VM is running!"
fi
```

When the vm is running but vm variable has a space the script doesnt work as expected

```
vm="PopOS VNC"
```

With the VM running  the value of vmstate is "VNC" not "running" as expected

With the vm stopped value is still "VNC"

However it works as expected for a vm name without a space (as below)

```
vm="CentOS10"
```

With the VM running  the value of vmstate is "running" as expected.

With the VM shutdown the value is "shut" as expected

Please can someone tell me how to get this to work with a vm that has a space in its name.

many thanks :)

edit
output of virsh list --all

```
 Id   Name                  State
--------------------------------------
 -    Big Sur               shut off
 -    True NAS              shut off
 -    CentOS10              shut off
 -    Debian-10             shut off
 -    dos_6.22              shut off
 -    Windows 95            shut off
 -    Gparted Live          shut off
 -    Popos AMD gpu         shut off
 -    PopOS VNC             shut off
 -    OpenSUSE              shut off
 -    Windows 98 VNC        shut off
 -    OpenSUSE2             shut off
 -    pfSense               shut off
```

output of script using set x

```
+ vm='PopOS VNC'
++ virsh list --all
++ awk '{ print $3}'
++ grep ' PopOS VNC '
+ vmstate=VNC
+ '[' VNC == x ']'
+ '[' VNC '!=' running ']'
+ echo 'VM is shut down'
VM is shut down
+ set +x
```

Comment: what do you mean 'the script doesnt work"? error message? no output? wrong output? what is the output from running `virsh list --all`? after you run the `virsh` call, what's being stored in the `vmstate` varaible (ie, what's the output from `typeset -p vmstate`)? please update the question with your answers

Comment: Sorry. When a vm name has a space the script will always return the vm as not running vmstate = VNC as does typeset -p vmstate. i will update the question. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a problem with quotes `"` or `'` or both.

In order to debug your script and see the actual commands expansion by the shell I use `set -x` to start commands echo and `set +x` to stop command echo.

Suggest to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
vm="PopOS VNC"
vmstate=$(virsh list --all | grep " $vm " | awk '{ print $3}')

if [ "$vmstate" == "x" ] || [ "$vmstate" != "running" ]
then
    echo "VM is shut down" 
else
    echo "VM is running!"
fi
set +x
```

I assume there is problem with variable expansion in `grep " $vm "`

Please post your results in the post.

In addition remember that `awk` default field separator is  . When your `$vm` is 2 worded the required `awk` field is shifted right to: `awk '{ print $4}'`, and if the `$vm` is 3 worded the required `awk` field is `awk '{ print $5}'`.

Maybe it is better to take the last word `awk '{ print $NF}'`

Or to take one word before the last word `awk '{ print $(NF - 1)}'`

Comment: Thankyou. Please see the results below in the original post

Comment: see my update about the `awk` shifting fields

Comment: Thankyou so much. Yes taking the last word works perfectly what ever the spacing in the vm name. Thankyou so much for your help i really appreciate it :)